# ASP.NET MVC Custom Route class - Can't get route data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to implement my own route class, inheriting from the default Route.

This is what my custom route class looks like:

```
public class FriendlyRoute : Route
{
    public FriendlyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, routeHandler)
    {

    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var actionName = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();

        routeData.Values["controller"] = fix(controllerName);
        routeData.Values["action"] = fix(actionName);

        return routeData;
    }

    private string fix(string name)
    {
        //Remove dashes: "my-controller" => "mycontroller"
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is accepting urls with dashes and routing the to the correct action ("my-controller/my-action" to "MyController/MyAction"), but I have some more plans for this custom route to.

To put my custom route class in action, I use the following route config:

```
routes.Add("Default",
           new FriendlyRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                             new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Public", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                             new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

This works fine! But I'm not happy with the url structure. I want to have some urls with no controller names only action names (e.g. "/about", "/contact") and some with controller names (e.g. "/mypage", "/mypage/invoices"). I start by using the default route class (not my own custom) and fix this problem:

```
routes.Add("MyPages",
           new Route("MyPage/{action}",
                     new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "MyPage", action = "Summary"}),
                     new MvcRouteHandler()));

routes.Add("Public",
           new Route("{action}/{id}",
                     new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Public", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                     new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

This also works fine, but now there's no support for urls with dashes. So I just swap in my custom route class into the route config:

```
routes.Add("MyPages",
           new FriendlyRoute("MyPage/{action}",
                             new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "MyPage", action = "Summary" }),
                             new MvcRouteHandler()));

routes.Add("Public",
           new FriendlyRoute("{action}/{id}",
                             new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Public", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
                             new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Now when I run the application I try to go to the default page ("/") it crashes because the call to base.GetRouteData(httpContext) in my FriendlyRoute.GetRouteData() returns null.

I'm all new to creating a custom route class, so any hints on what I' doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the additional two routes, when the root url is hit ("/") it will be processed against route definitions sequentially top to bottom until a match is made. So now for the first route `"MyPage/{action}"` it will call the `public abstract RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext);` method, which in turn matches the url with the route definition and check for constraints. It returns a `RouteValueDictionary` object in case of match and constraint check, `null` otherwise. So for the first route definition it is bound to return null as the url does not match. You should add a null check as foollowing

```
if (routeData != null)
{
    var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var actionName = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();

    routeData.Values["controller"] = Fix(controllerName);
    routeData.Values["action"] = Fix(actionName);
}
```

relevant resource: [Route.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Routing/Route@cs/1305376/Route@cs)

hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I get it. All routes defintions are called until a matching one is found, and it is supposed to return null when the url doesn't match. You set me off in the right direction. Thanks! :)