# How to automatically convert ASP.NET MVC action names to dashed URLs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, pascalcasing

Let's say I have this action method in my `ApplicationController`

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethodName()
{
    ...
}
```

I want this (and all methods that doesn't have a specific route) method's route to be `/application/my-action-method-name` without manually specifying it. Some special route or package that can convert action methods names in PascalCase to dashed routes.

Is there something like that?

Comment: Looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145387/asp-net-mvc-custom-route-class-cant-get-route-data) is exactly what you're looking for. Dashes and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this project](http://www.bousie.co.uk/blog/allow-dashes-within-urls-using-asp-net-mvc4/) which is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseDashedRoute/) that will convert all action method names to lowercased-dashed-routes.

Comment: This should be the default route system in ASP.NET MVC, IMHO.